# PHP exec another command after composer project created

Tags: php

After installing a package with php and composer, I want to enter that directory, I will copy a few files after entering it, but I could not enter it. how to do it?

```
<?php
$name = uniqid();

shell_exec('composer create-project laravel/laravel ' . $name);

shell_exec('cd ' . $name);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "could not enter it"? What do you think the above code has as visible side effects? You can't `cd` a parent process by running `cd` in a child process.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I want to enter the created folder and copy the controllers and models from another yard to the new project, but the other commands do not work because the first command is not finished.

Comment: That's your interpretation. Now, what are your actual observations? What makes you think the first command is not finished?

Comment: The directory name appears next to the name in the terminal. After the composer command runs, I want it to enter the newly created directory, but it doesn't, which shows that it's not working. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can't post a comment yet, so I'm shooting this in the dark.
What does "could not enter it" mean? give us the error you receive.

Although, I can somewhat tell that it's simply not doing what you think it should do.

`shell_exec` spawns a shell, and executes the command in it, then terminates the shell (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec).
This means that if you execute a `cd` inside a shell-exec, as soon as it ends you are "back" in the directory you were before (you actually never changed directory).

Maybe you want to use `chdir()` (the PHP function, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) to change directory and then execute something while being in it? Like:

```
<?php
$name = uniqid();

shell_exec('composer create-project laravel/laravel ' . $name);

chdir($name);

shell_exec('something');
```

I'd say if you want to copy files, there's the useful `copy($source, $destination)` function in PHP (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), but I believe you're better off just using bash or any other batch language to do all of this.

Comment: Let's say there is a controller called XController.php in the home directory. and I want to copy it to controller folder after new project is created